# cart always empty Prestashop 1.7.2.4

Tags: php, ajax, cart, prestashop-1.7

I have a cart problem. Whenever I add a product to the cart, it remains empty. (cookies, caché, have been cleaned) (www.domain.fr or domain.fr does not change a thing)(enable disable SSL don't change a thing). Products are in stock. In the back office, each time a add a product to the cart it creates a new cart, but it still doesn't show on the client's cart page
Please help to fix the problem

My site: http://www.melo4kids.fr
Version PHP: 7.1.15
Version PrestaShop : 1.7.2.4

here is an image of

[image: empty basket]

here is an image of

[image: back office carts client]

Comment: Have the same problem on 1.7.2.2 do you resolved it @Melo4kids?